# Click event fires on different button control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have following HTML code, where I add items to cart and then finally click submit.

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <div>
     <select id="available-options" multiple>
         <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
         <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
         <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
      </select>
     <button id="add-button" aria-label="Add">Add</button>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="box-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Update</button>
</div>
```

I have below Javascript

```
  window.onload = function () {
      const addButton = document.getElementById("add-button");

       addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
       const selected = availableOptions.selectedOptions;
       for (let i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
          const option = selected[i];
          selectedOptions.appendChild(option);
         }
     });
   }
```

When I click `add` button,  both button events are getting fired!

Comment: What do you mean, "both button events"? There's only one button event handler in the code you posted.

Comment: Oh, possibly your problem is that the default "type" for a button is "submit", so your "add" button is *also* a "submit" button.

Answer (score 1):

The default [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#type) of *button* element is *submit* that causes the submission of the *form*. You can either specify the *button* `type="button"` or prevent the default behavior using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

**Demo:**

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <button id="add-button" aria-label="Add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Update</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    const addButton = document.getElementById("add-button");

    addButton.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting

      //other code here
      console.log("Add button clicked");
    });
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.stopPropagation()` inside the event handler.

This issue might be come because of the way of Javascript manage the events. Javascript by default follows the **events bubbling**. So here, when the target event is being completed, it will also called its next parent level event handler or better to say, **event bubbling up to its parent** and it will go till the final DOM event. So, to prevent this, we have to specifically mention `event.stopPropagation()` inside the handler method.

I think above answer will help you. I'm also giving a reference link on this topic, please check this [reference link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/event-bubbling-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=What%20is%20Event%20Bubbling%3F,gets%20to%20the%20root%20element.).